# Spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles in chemistry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Electrons and protons are spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles, so under a rotation by 360$^\circ$, their wavefunction changes by a sign.  They are also commonly found alone in chemical reactions, especially protons (H$^+$ ions).  Does this 720$^\circ$ rotation-invariance property have any important effects on chemistry?

Answer (score 2):

I almost voted to close your question as a duplicate of [How do you rotate spin of an electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167469/how-do-you-rotate-spin-of-an-electron). This would be controversial because the question looks related at a first glance, but ACuriousMind's answer to that question also (indirectly) answers this question.

When we talk about rotating an electron, or any fermion, we are not talking about a physical rotation in the sense of rotating any macroscopic body. [ACuriousMind explains this very clearly here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167469/how-do-you-rotate-spin-of-an-electron/167470#167470). So the rotational properties of the fermion wavefunction have no direct physical relevance to chemistry. If you rotate an electron by $2\pi$ it's still the same electron.

For completeness I should make the obvious comment that the fact electrons are fermions means they obey Fermi-Dirac statistics and this underlies all of chemistry. So in this sense the rotational behaviour is intimately related to chemistry. However I assume you're asking specifically about rotation and not about the effect of the electron being a fermion.

Answer (score -1):

In quantum physics and quantum chemistry , spin isnt an actual rotation of a particle , it is just a quantum property of a particle.

Comment: Electron spin is angular momentum in every sense.

Comment: No it isnt . It is a quantum property of a particle.