# Do one-half spin phenomena breakdown equivalence between active and passive transformations?

Tags: reference-frames, quantum-spin, coordinate-systems, fermions, spinors

If i rotate a physical system by say 10 degrees it is equivalent to my self rotate -10 degrees.

but if i rotate an electron 360 degrees it spin state have a detectable minus sing. now if instead of the electron myself rotate in opposite direction i think there will be no detectable change in electron. it is same as before "I" rotate.

so i can ask is my note is true? or equivalently: do one-half spin phenomena breakdown equivalence of  between active and passive transformation?

Comment: The statement *"if I rotate an electron 360 degrees it spin state have a detectable minus sing"* [sic] is an oversimplification, see [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167470/50583). That minus sign is *not* detectable unless as a relative phase, i.e. compared to another state that is not being rotated, and this is a rotation in Hilbert space, not physical space. That said, I am not sure what exactly your question is - can you elaborate where you see this "breakdown"?

Comment: I think active and passive transformations are mainly different things. so i'm thinking about an experiment which shows this difference. @ACuriousMind